# Is it okay to use both Cloudflare IP Block and IP Range Block List together?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ip, cloudflare

Like this in htaccess file which I have already for cloudflare:

```
 SetEnvIf CF-IPCountry UA BuzzOff=1
 Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=BuzzOff
```

And if I also use this code below can I also be block the misses traffic?
I mean the above code which comply with cloudflare leaks some IPs from Ukraine and I'd like to completely block them by htaccess.

```
# -------------------------------------------------------
# Free IP2Location Firewall List by Country
# Source: https://www.ip2location.com/free/visitor-blocker
# Last Generated: 03 Apr 2018 18:43:08 GMT
# [Important] Please update this list every month
# -------------------------------------------------------
<Limit GET HEAD POST>
order allow,deny
allow from all
deny from 2.21.89.0/24
deny from 2.21.173.0/24
deny from 5.1.0.0/19
deny from 5.8.32.0/24
deny from 5.8.34.0/24
deny from 5.8.60.0/24
deny from 5.8.62.0/24
deny from 5.22.156.0/22
deny from 5.34.176.0/22
deny from 5.34.182.0/23
deny from 5.53.112.0/21
deny from 5.56.24.0/21
deny from 5.57.64.0/21
deny from 5.58.0.0/16
deny from 5.59.54.0/24
deny from 5.59.104.0/23
deny from 5.83.16.0/21
deny from 5.104.32.0/19
deny from 5.105.0.0/16
deny from 5.149.120.0/21
deny from 5.149.208.0/20
deny from 5.153.128.0/19
deny from 5.153.160.0/22
deny from 5.153.168.0/21
deny from 5.153.176.0/20
deny from 5.188.61.0/24
......
</Limit>
```

Comment: If you are using cloudflare you are most likely seeing the IPs from cloudflare edgeservers. They may have been used because they are closer to the client. So you may get a Ukraine Cloudflare IP, but the customer is from Western Russia.

Comment: @xsign thats not an answer to my above question.

Comment: You cannot block user ips with cloudflare unless you have the enteprise plan. Do you have this one?

Comment: No I dont have but using htaccess will block them. Isnt there right?

Comment: You cannot block user ips when your domain is assigned to cloudflare (and you do not have the enterprise plan). You can block the edgeservers only, which will result in too many customers being blocked. It will not solve your problem.